# Can Offset Fetch next clause be applied on SQL view?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a SQL view and want to perform Offset fetch next clause to achieve server-side pagination for my application BUT when I used Offset fetch clause on View the result is not getting filtered properly I can see the same rows on the next result set

```
Create view MyView AS
Select Id, Name, LastUpdatedDate from Table1
Union
Select Id, Name, LastUpdatedDate from Table2

Select * From MyView
Order by LastUpdatedDate Desc
Offset 0 Rows Fetch Next 14 Rows Only
```

When I run the above Select query I see some records of the first result set where I used 0 Offset, are showing on the next result set when I used 1 as Offset value.

Any idea about this?
Many thanks

Comment: Of course you're going to get some of the same rows. If you `OFFSET` by `0` and `FETCH` the next 14 you get the "1st" to "14th" rows. if you then `OFFSET` by `1` and `FETCH` the next 14 you get the "2nd" to "15th" rows. 13 of those are in the prior data set. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Also, I'd be very surprised if `LastUpdatedDate` was "unique enough" to give a *deterministic* ordering across all rows. When doing this sort of paging you need to ensure you have enough `ORDER BY` expressions such that a unique combination will be produced for every single row.

Comment: What Larnu is (correctly) saying is the offset is for one record, not for one page. You have to multiply by the page size to get the correct offset value. Now it's possible this is a wording mistake in writing the question, rather than in your code or process. Can you clarify that for us?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a stored procedure to retrieve the data. You can pass the page number and multiply it by 14 as the offset or just pass the offset like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySp
    @offset as int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select * From MyView
    Order by LastUpdatedDate Desc
    Offset @offset Rows Fetch Next 14 Rows Only
END
```

and call it this way to get page two in this case:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[MySp]
        @offset = 14

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```